# Birational equivalence of hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-space, birational-geometry

Consider all the smooth hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$, for $d,n$ general enough. If $X$ and $Y$ are birational equivalent, then I think they are not necessarily isomorphic. I want to know that:

> what is the dimension of birational equivalent classes of hypersurfaces?

For example, for $(n,d)=(3,3)$, all smooth cubic surfaces are birational equivalent, so the dimension is $0$. I would like to know how should we approach this in general.

Comment: This is a very hard question. For example, for $n=$ and $d=3$ (cubic fourfolds), it is not known whether or not all of them are rational.

Comment: Oops, my previous comment should have read "...$n=5$ and $d=3$".

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti Thanks for your comment. Yeah I see, this seems a question totally unknown.